# If condition joined by & operator not functioning as expected

Tags: php

I came across this patch of code today, and I can't understand why does it work this way.

```
$action = "outstanding";
$id = "2733";

//first
if($action == "outstanding")
    if(is_numeric($id))
        echo "bye";
//second
if( ($action == "oustanding") && (is_numeric($id)))
    echo "hi";
```

Based on my understanding, the first nd second if conditions are exactly the same. However, the result I am getting is this:

```
bye
```

Why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: please.... before asking, check the equlaization conditions.... we are NOT here to spot your typos.

Comment: voting to close myself

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in the second "outstanding"

You spelled it "ouStanding"

Comment: oh gosh. what a simple error overlooked. thanks

Comment: Completely understandable. I had to paste it into my IDE before I saw it. Spellcheck should be in every IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because $action == "oustanding" which should be $action == "outstanding".

Answer (score 0):

```
$action = "outstanding";
    $id = "2733";

    //first
    if($action == "outstanding")
        if(is_numeric($id))
            echo "bye";
    //second
    if( ($action == "outstanding") && (is_numeric($id)))
        echo "hi";
```

There was a typo on the last line, it's "outstanding" instead of "oustanding".

In this way, it returns:

```
byehi
```